# Paypal response on localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have the following hardcoded form in a view:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="mymail@mymail.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Attack Announcer" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="2ca168a959bb48e28a2ddb4b4640c568" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.01" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="?????" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="?????" />
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="??????" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
    <input type="image" name="submit"
           src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif"
           alt="PayPal — The safer, easier way to pay online." />
    <img src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif"
         width="1" height="1" alt="" />
</form>
```

How can I take the response message after the transaction is completed (on localhost)?
For example if I have some action like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PaypalConfirmation(???????????)
{

      // ........................

      return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to tell it the success url and fail url, that on success transaction go the this url and on failed transaction go to this url, you have to pass the url via hidden fields of **return** and **cancel_return**:

### URL where paypal will redirect if transaction successfull:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")" />
```

### URL where paypal will redirect if transaction not Successful:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")" />
```

Also refer this [**Question (Asp.net Paypal Return Url Requirement)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393693/asp-net-paypal-return-url-requirement)